# variable should not reset when calling the function again?

Tags: c, function, pointers, null

I want the value of a pointer variable to be initialized to `NULL` at the start of the execution. This variable is used in a function and its value may also get changed within the function. But I do not want the value of this variable to reset to `NULL` whenever a function call is made. Instead, its value should be equal to the updated value from its previous function call. Cannot use global variables.

```
void function(struct node *variable) {
  // changes value of pointer variable to something else
  variable = something;
}

void another_function(void) {
  // have to be initialised before passing in as argument or else will raise error
  struct node *variable = NULL;

  function(variable);
}

// then calling this function multiple times in main
another_function();
another_function();
```

help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is what `static` is for.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the pointer variable `variable` is local to `another_function`. It does not live outside of this scope.

Secondly, when you pass it to `function`, the `variable` parameter of that function is also local to that function. You immediately assign a value to that local variable, but that doesn't change the `variable` you passed in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **static** keyword when declaring your initial pointer variable.
It will only be initialized when first encountered during the execution.

But as for now, your code will probably not do what you intend it to do.
The pointer `variable` in `function` is local and will have no effect on the value of `variable` in `another_function`.
You should use a pointer of pointer (also called a double-pointer or a nested pointer) for this effect.

Here is an example of how to use a double-pointer :

```
struct node {
    int value;
};


void function(struct node** variable) {

    if(*variable == NULL) {
        *variable = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        
        (*variable)->value = 1;
    }

    printf("Value of variable is %d\n", (*variable)->value);

    // Creating another struct node just for the demonstration
    struct node* newnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newnode->value = (*variable)->value + 1;

    *variable = newnode;
}

void another_function() {
    static struct node* variable = NULL;

    function(&variable);
}
```

Basically, you pass the address of a pointer (located on the stack, which will always have a memory address)  which let you modify the content of this pointer (a memory address on the heap) in the receiving function.

When you are dereferencing `variable` in `function`, what you get is not a value but another pointer.

Also parenthesis are important in this case.

Nested pointers can really be confusing, I hope that my explanation is somewhat clear.

To really understand how it works you need to understand what it's on the stack and what it's on the heap. But maybe this is an explanation for another time.

Of course, there is no memory management in this example and what I wrote contains memory leaks from all `struct node` that never are deallocated.
You should figure out how to do it depending on your program architecture.

Comment: can you explain how i would use pointer of pointer in my example